# Changing variables in Model from Controller with only ENUM to direct

Tags: java, javafx, model-view-controller, enums, observable

I'm trying to change instance variables in my Model from a method in a Controller using only an ENUM to identify instance variable it should change.

So my model has a number of Attribute instance variables:

```
public class Model(){
private Attribute physicalAttack = new Attribute(PHYSICAL_ATTACK,"Physical Attack",0,0);
//so on...
}
```

The Attribute class looks like this:

```
public class Attribute {

    private ModifierType type;
    private String name;
    private IntegerProperty baseValue;
    private IntegerProperty effectsModifier;

    public Attribute(ModifierType type, String name, int baseValue, int effectsModifier) {
        this.type = type;
        this.name = name;
        this.baseValue = new SimpleIntegerProperty(baseValue);
        this.effectsModifier = new SimpleIntegerProperty(effectsModifier);
    }
```

And the ModifierType enum:

```
public enum ModifierType {
    XP,
    GOLD,
    HEALTH,
    PHYSICAL_ATTACK_BASE,
    PHYSICAL_ATTACK_EFFECT,
    // so on...
}
```

Now I have an Effect class which is used to model a 'buff' in a game.

```
public class Effect {
    String name;
    String description;
    IntegerProperty duration;
    ArrayList<EffectModifier> modifierList;

    public Effect (String name, String description, int duration) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.duration = new SimpleIntegerProperty(duration);
        this.modifierList = new ArrayList<>();

    }
}
```

And the EffectModifier is used to suggest the Attribute to modify and the amount using the same enum:

```
public class EffectModifier {
    private ModifierType type;
    private int change;

    public EffectModifier(ModifierType type, int change) {
        this.type = type;
        this.change = change;
    }
}
```

My model also has an ObservableList of Effects to keep track of the currently active buffs:

```
private ObservableList<Effect> currentEffectsList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
```

I'm using a Model-View-Controller so I have a controller class which has a ListChangeListener applied to the ObservableList so that whenever I add a new Effect it updates on the view.

The trouble I'm having is finding a way such that whenever a new Effect is added, it's ArrayList of modifiers are looped through, and from the Enum each modifier has - it finds the appropriate Attribute, and updates the appropriate IntegerProperty. So if I have an Effect with this modifier added to it:

```
Effect e1 = new Effect("The Witches Blessing","Attack Boost",10);
        e1.addModifier(new EffectModifier(ModifierType.PHYSICAL_ATTACK_EFFECT, 20));
```

It will add 20 to the effects modifier of the physicalAttack variable in the model, *and it will also remove the effect when it is removed from the ObservableList.*

Comment: You have a `ListChangeListener` that updates your view whenever an `Effect` is added, yes?  So why not another `ListChangeListener` implementation that updates the `Attributes` in your model?

Comment: That's fine but it's the implementation of it knowing when an Effect is added or removed so it knows to add or remove the modifiers, and still the implementation of using the ENUM to get to the property.

Comment: Where do _modifiers_ need to be added to or removed from?

Comment: The ArrayList in the Effects class

Comment: I assumed we were talking about updating the `Attribute`s in the model when an `Effect` is added into the `currentEffectsList`.  Did I misunderstand?

Comment: Yeah that's correct. I thought you were asking about the EffectModifier objects: But yes, the modifier value (eg 20) has to be add/minus the appropriate Attribute in the model.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172458/discussion-between-kevin-anderson-and-user3317592).